# correct way to handle hibernate @Version column with json responses

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

The below code is used to update an `Account` hibernate object.  The problem is that the Account has a version column `@Version`.  Hibernate will automatically update the merged account but it seems that this happens after the response has been serialized into json.  Therefore if the account is updated again I get a `StaleObjectStateException` as the version sent back to the client was the original one.  I realise that I can manually update the object before I send it back but is there a nicer option?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/{1}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public final Account update(@RequestBody final Account account) {
    return accountSerivice.merge(account);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt this be @Transactional ? your service method i mean? Since the transactional annotation is an after returning advice. it would flush the entity when it exits out of the outermost transaction. This should update the @Version number too.

Comment: I am pretty sure the service is @Transactional, I will do some more debugging Monday to see what is going on and exactly when the update statement is executing.

Comment: Yes, your are correct.  I checked again and the version was in fact being updated, the trouble was with an @Transient method on the domain object that was trying to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Call `flush()` on the hibernate session. This will write the pending changes to the database and increment the version number.